# Java MimeMail : getting extra characters after decoding

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

i am using standard java javax.mail.internet.MimePartDataSource.getInputStream to get the attachment associated with email. The issue i am facing is:

`the size of the file attached is 10950 bytes(excel).
The size of file i get using MimePartDataSource is 14810 bytes.`

If i remove the last extra character and try to open it, it works fine; but if i try to open without deleting the extra bytes  a pop-up gets generated indicating 'want to recover the file?'
and then if i say yes , it works.

I was facing this issue with excel and pdf .
Can you put some light in it?

Thanks ,
Arindam

Comment: Can you show the code you use to extract the attachment?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using the available() method to determine how much data to save.  That doesn't work.  Use the approach described in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#readattach).

Answer (score 0):

I am using another approach to deal this problem and got success. Previously i was using getInputStream , which was adding some extra data after decoding somehow .Now, i am fetching data using getRawInputStream and decoding it explicitly which is preserving the real attachment.